# How to change context of Word's context menu?

Tags: microsoft-word, context-menu

A context menu should always provide the appropriate options for the current context. So far. Unfortunately, Microsoft Word does not recognize the right context.

For example: In track changes mode, if a word is misspelled, the spell checking context menu appears on right click. But when I right click an equation, the track changes context menu appears, not the equation context menu.

How can I explicitly set the context that I currently need?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way in Word for you to choose the specific Context Menu to display upon a right click event. However, using VBA and depending on the version of Word you are using, you can add choice options to specific context menus.